# How can I find out how shifts in a country's fiscal policies affect its economic health?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, modeling, predictive-models

I have the values of certain variables for 20 years for different countries... I am unable to understand how to use the values of a particular variable for 20 years. Could anyone suggest how I should go about this?

Predictor variables:

- Imports of Goods and Services
- Industry value added
- Trade in services
- Revenue excluding grants
- GNI per capita
- Gross saving
- CPIA fiscal policy rating

Outcome variables:

- GDP growth (annual change as %)
- GDP per capita
- Inflation of customer prices

Comment: This is a time series analysis. Word of warning, there is more noise in economic data than trend. You will probably find some sort of "pattern" that, if checked on another dataset, will not explain the trend.

Comment: Thanks... I am not much familiar with time series analysis. Can it be done using Regression analysis ? Where can I learn to do it ?

Comment: If you want to do a regression, then set up your dataset with each date as a separate individual. Then regress with time as an independent variable.

Comment: You want to start by googling "panel data".  There is a lot to learn if you're starting from scratch...

Comment: Even for a trained time series expert, it would be difficult to provide a useful model that is able to answer this question in an unbiased way.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a vector autoregressive model, to model each country individually. The model would look something like this,

$$\mathbf{y}_t = c+A_i\mathbf{y}_{t-1}+\cdots+A_p+\mathbf{y}_{t-p}+u_t,$$ where $\mathbf{y}_t=(y_{1,t},y_{2,t},\dots,y_{n,t})'$ and  $u_t$ is $IIDN(0,\sigma)$

So you would estimate one vector autoregressive model for each variable for each country, regressing on past values of the outcome variable and past values of your predictors. After you find a model that fit you can look at the coefficients from the variables of interest, which in your case seems to be the fiscal policy rating variable. If you think this sounds interesting, I would recommend Applied Time Series Econometrics, by Lütkepohl and Krätzig, Cambridge University Press, The Edinburgh Building, Cambridge CB2 2RU, UK, 2004.